# Build Configuration in Visual Studio from Qmake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, build

I use qmake (qmake -tp vc) to generate vcxproj files for Visual Studio 2010. The problem is, only 'release' and 'debug' solution configurations are generated.

I want to create another configuration, call it configX, which will set another precompiler define that we don't want in the other builds. I can't figure out how to accomplish this in a Qt Pro file.

Can anyone provide some assistance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread on qtcentre forum](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/45047-Multiple-build-configurations-with-qmake), you define multiple configuration using the `CONFIG` variable when you call `qmake` from command line.
Then, you just have to make a script that call `qmake` multiple times with different `CONFIG` values, which will let you build a multi-configuration solution.
I did not test it myself yet, though I plan to.
Looking at [this page](http://qxrunner.systest.ch/qxrunner-installation/) (QxRunner installation) it seems possible !

Comment: Thanks! That solution is not quite as nice as having the solution configuration available from the Visual Studio drop-down... but its better than maintaining separate project files with different defines.